# Rest API enveloping or not

Tags: rest, api

I have one question that i am finding hard to clearly identify the correct answer.

My API has one endpoint that does pagination. So, in the response i have to return to the client the total number of lines afected by the query. The count of records in practice.

I have read that, i should be passing metadata like what i want in the body, enveloping it, but i have also read that, it is not ok to afect the body with meta-data and that the future is to return only non meta-data on the body meaning that it must be on the response header.

O'reilly

`If the information you are conveying through a custom HTTP header is important for the correct interpretation of the request or response, include that information in the body of the request or response or the URI used for the request. Avoid custom headers for such usages.`

So, my question is, what is the correct approach to the problem? Should i pass the number of lines in response headers or put it in the message body.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think there's that much of a distinction between data and meta-data. The fact is, the total count _is_ data and it's useful to the client. I like your O'Reilly definition. If you follow that, definitely don't put the information in the header.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, you could use an envelope in the response payload:

```json
{
  "data": [...],
  "paging": {
    "first": "http://api.example.com/foo?page=1&size=10",
    "previous": "http://api.example.com/foo?page=2&size=10"
    "next": "http://api.example.com/foo?page=4&size=10"
    "last": "http://api.example.com/foo?page=5&size=10"
  }
}
```

A [similar approach](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-3) is described in the [RFC 5005](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005): each page of results is a separate resource, which contains hyperlinks to the previous and next page of results

---

You also could use the [`Link`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-3) header (line breaks are just for readability purposes):

```
Link: <http://api.example.com/foo?page=1&size=10>; rel="first", 
      <http://api.example.com/foo?page=2&size=10>; rel="previous",
      <http://api.example.com/foo?page=4&size=10>; rel="next", 
      <http://api.example.com/foo?page=5&size=10>; rel="last"
```

Check the [link relations registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml).

---

For returning the number of records, I've seen some APIs using custom headers such as `X-Total-Count`, but I don't recommend such approach. Send those details in the response payload then.

Comment: Well. That is not the use case. I want to send the total record in database. I know how to resolve paging already.  My question is, where will i send the number of items on the database. In body or header.

Comment: @DiogoAleixo I've seen some APIs using custom headers such as `X-Total-Count`, but I don't recommend such approach. Send those details in the response payload then.

Comment: Thanks @Cassio. I alread saw X-Total-Count. Why dont you recomment such approach? Do you have any readings that support the sentence?

Comment: @DiogoAleixo HTTP is an _extensible protocol_. Non-standard headers are allowed and can be used for _informational purposes_. But I don't see any harm in including such details in the response payload.